# In CSS, how do I apply style to all but the nested element?

Tags: html, css

As an example, if I want Text1 to be red but not Text2:

```
<div class="red">
Text1
<p class="notred">Text2</p>
</div>
```

I tried this in css:

```
.red :not(.notred) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Trying this, it does not apply style to either Text1 or Text2.

Comment: You could just make another rule for notred and give it a different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS selectors must target an element (with some few exceptions like `::first-line` pseudoelement). `Text1` is not an element, so (again, ignoring `::first-line`) you cannot target it with a single rule. As @JHeth says, use two rules: one to set the red for `.red`, and another to cancel it in `.notred`.

```css
.red { color: red; }
.notred { color: black; }
```

```html
<div class="red">
  Text1
  <p class="notred">Text2</p>
</div>
```

Of course, if you are sure `Text1` will fit in one line, you can cheat, but it is a very specific solution for a very specific situation:

```css
.red::first-line { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="red">
  Text1
  <p class="notred">Text2</p>
</div>
```

To explain why your CSS selector `.red :not(.notred)` doesn't work, it targets a descendant element of `.red` which is not `.notred`. `.red` has only one descendant element (remember, `Text1` is a text node, which is not an element!), and it is `.notred` — so the rule doesn't apply to anything. Here would be an example where your CSS selector would apply:

```css
.red :not(.notred) { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <p>Text1</p>
  <p class="notred">Text2</p>
</div>
```

Here, `<p>Text1</p>` is an element, is not `.notred`, and is a descendant of a `.red` element, so it can be found by your selector.

Comment: What if I wanted to do the same thing but apply display:none to all but the nested element? Is there any way that display:none can be reversed?

Comment: @alexn `display: none` would remove the entire element, including all nested elements, not just a portion of the element

Comment: In contrast to `display: none`, which actually removes elements from layout (so there are no sub-elements to reverse it on), you may be looking for `visibility: hidden`, which just makes it not displayed (which can totally get reversed by descendants).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.notred {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  Text1
  <p class="notred">Text2</p>
</div>
```

You can achieve it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the text in a div like that without giving it a class or selector, because calling the red container will take all of its children elements into effect without specifying one first. So instead, you'd have to style the tags individually or specify a class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
   .red .text1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="red">
    <p class="text1">text1</p>
    <p class="notred">Text2</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```